# What's wrong with this geojson file?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to add [this geojson file](https://disk.yandex.com/d/8Ygxja4EO8qAUQ) to my Leaflet project, using the following code:

```
var iba = L.geoJSON.ajax('data/iba/iba.geojson').addTo(map);
```

This geojson I have created with dummy data using the QGIS export option, but I don't know if that's relevant.
Anyway, I don't get any error message in the browser's console, but the layer doesn't show up in the map. I have made a test with [this other file](https://disk.yandex.com/d/ZstROWt9aikhsg), using the same above code (changing only the file name, as they are both in the same folder) and it works.

What's wrong with the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A valid GeoJSON is only in EPSG:4326. Your file is in EPSG:25830.
You can set the CRS when you export the file in QGIS.

Comment: A valid GeoJSON is not in EPSG:4326 it's in CRS:84.  GeoJSON is long/lat, EPSG:4326 is lat/long!